# How to switch between 2 activities while keeping their contents intact?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a main_activity calling activity B. Activity B will update a few things on main_activity, while updating a few things on itself. A back button press on activity B will bring it back to main_activity. I managed to keep activity B's contents intact, but not the main_activity (being recreated). I referred to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435678/hide-activity-in-android?answertab=votes#tab-top).

What I want is to keep both main_activity's and activity B's contents intact. How can I achieve that?

This is my code:

main_activity calls activity B on menu select:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(mainActivity.this, Activity_B.class);
//startActivityForResult(mIntent);
mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

activity-B back press:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(Activity_B.this, mainActivity.class);
    mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
    startActivity(mIntent);
}
```

Comment: @artm. What did you edit? I don't see any changes.

Comment: Click on "edited nn mins ago" link, you'll see the changes I made. Simply removed some white space.

Comment: I think you must remove addFlags from your code

Answer (score 0):

You can save contents of `MainActivity` that you want to update in `ActivityB` using `SharedPreferences` and in `MainActivity` get the value from `SharedPreferences` and display.

```
//Save something in Activity B
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor e = settings.edit();

e.putString("variableName", "a string value");

e.commit();

//Retrieve in MainActivity
String mContent = settings.getString("variableName", "");
```

`SharedPreferences` will store the value even if you exit the app. You can also access the values stored in `SharedPreferences` from any other class.

Answer (score 0):

U need to start your activity  from main activity as below

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(mainActivity.this, Activity_B.class); 
   startActivityForResult(mIntent,PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST(int));
```

**in activity B ( for set result to update your main activity by Intent ) **

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() {
 Intent mIntent = new Intent ();
   mIntent.putExtra("some_key",someData);
  mIntent.putExtra("Some_mey2",someData2);
setResult(RESULT_OK,mIntent);
}
```

**handling result in your main_activity from activity b and update ui of main_activity ** `

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int.    requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're     responding to
     if (requestCode ==    PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {       // Make sure the request was     successful
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
someTextfield.settext(data.getStringExtra("Some_key");
     }
    }
}
```